# Rabbit MQ support in Azure

Tags: azure, rabbitmq, messaging, azure-queues

I need to read and publish messages to a Rabbit MQ instance from multiple app services on Azure.

Could anyone please suggest the Azure service that I should be using to host the Rabbit MQ instance?

Answer (score 7):

Checkout RabbitMQ as a service on https://www.cloudamqp.com/

It's available on Azure, the free plan is somewhat restricted on regions but the paid plans are much better supported across Azure regions.

Comment: I should also mention that RabbitMQ is also available as a trigger on Azure functions

Answer (score 5):

There is no Managed option available in Azure, you can consider installing in two ways,

- Create individual Linux VM’s, Install RabbitMQ on it, Connect the RabbitMQ nodes installed in each VM.
- Install RabbitMQ Cluster package provided by [`Bitnami in Azure`](https://bitnami.com/stack/rabbitmq/containers).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We will try the Bitnami cluster.

Comment: @AnudeepSai, could you help advise what was the solution chosen finally?

Comment: @Jacob I believe we finally ended up creating a VM and hosting Rabbit MQ cluster on it.